# Flask sessions: PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME not being set correctly

Tags: python-3.x, session, flask, flask-session

So I am using a flask session. I am using the filesystem type so that I can store more session data than I otherwise could. My users want to keep session timeouts long, and the site uses minimal server storage, so this is fine. However, when I try to set the timeout session to 24 hours below, it still times out after 30 minutes.

```
application = Flask(__name__)
SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
application.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
application.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
application.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(hours = 24)

application.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY

Session(application)



@application.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    application.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(hours = 24)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found the issue, which was in the line :  `SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)`. Every time the app restarted (idle window in browser reloaded), session data was erased as a new secret key was generated, meaning the browser could not find the cookies it needed. I generated one key, externally, and then hardcoded this value into my code so it is the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the line with session.permanent =true to session.modified = True and see if it works then.

Comment: I believe I have found the issue, which was in the line :  ``` SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32) ```. Every time the app restarted (idle window in browser reloaded), session data was erased as a new secret key was generated, meaning the browser could not find the cookies it needed. I generated one key, externally, and then hardcoded this value into my code so it is the same every time.

Comment: Well, that would only be the issue if session expires due to restarting the flask app. Nevertheless, normally you would store the secret key as env variable and not hardcoded in your application. In your config file you can then get the secret key like this: SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

Comment: So I actually believe now that the problem is with AWS,for a few reasons. When running on localhost, the sessions were indeed 24 hours; only when deployed did the sessions time out. Also, the session timeouts were tough to predict -- they seemed to not be based on strict timing but instead on inactivity.I suspect that AWS clears server-side session data like the filesystem session type i have implemented after a certain amount of time spent inactive.